# Process video in OpenCV, without playing it

Tags: opencv, video, vision, face

I have code, which is able to capture faces, when it crossing a line in video, after that app will save it to local direction. Is it possible to process this application, with prerecorded video, without playing it.

Means, if I have 2 hours video, how can I save all faces in video, within few minutes?

Comment: you don't have to render the video, but you will still have to capture/decode each frame and run your detection method on each frame. Typically that needs about 100-200 ms per frame and so it will still need a lot of time for your 2 hours video (but depends on your detection .method and your hardware).

Answer (score 1):

To work on two hours of video in a few minutes, you will need a few tricks like

1. resizing the video so that you can save some time used in frame
   acquisition.
2. skipping frames and settling for a frame rate like 6 to
   10 fps, assuming that faces do not move too far across during that
   time
3. performing face detection only in a small search area of the
   image
4. Tuning the face detector to work as fast as possible
5. making your login for "crossing the line" as simple as
   possible

With a good computer and OpenCV built to use GPU, you might make it.